# Jech The Axiom of Choice Lemma 6.5

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

I was working through the proof of the Jech-Sochor Embedding Theorem in Jech's "The Axiom of Choice", but I didn't understand the proof of Lemma 6.5 on page 89, which I copied below.

> Lemma $6.5$. $(\mathscr{P}^\alpha(A)^\mathscr{V})^\sim = \mathscr{P}^\alpha(\tilde{A})^\mathscr{N}.$
>
> Proof. It suffices to show that the right-hand side is included in the left-hand side. The proof is by induction; we show that if $x \in \mathscr{P}^\alpha(A)^\mathscr{V}$ and $y \subseteq x$, $y \in \mathscr{N}$, then there exists $z \in \mathscr{V}$ such that $y = \tilde{z}$. Let $\underline{y}$ be a name for $y$. Note that every descending sequence of less than $\kappa$ conditions has a lower bound. Since $|x| < \kappa$, we may use the same argument as in the proof of Lemma $5.12$ (or Problem $5.5$), to obtain $p \in G$ which decides $\underline{\tilde{t}} \in \underline{y}$ for all $t \in x$. It follows that $y = \tilde{z}$, where $z = \{t \in x \ : \ p \Vdash \tilde{\underline{t}} \in \underline{y} \}$. By Lemma $6.4$, since $\tilde{z} \in \mathscr{N}$, we have $z \in \mathscr{V}$.

I have two questions.

(i) I was trying to obtain such $p \in G$ which decides $\underline{\tilde{t}} \in \underline{y}$ for all $t \in x$ as follows. For each $t \in y$, let $D_t$ be the set of conditions that force $\underline{\tilde{t}} \in \underline{y}$. It suffices to show that $\bigcap_{t \in y} D_t$ is dense. The forcing notion used here is $\kappa$-closed, so it remains to show that each $D_t$ is dense. But I don't see why this is the case.

(ii) I didn't understand why the claim proved in this lemma would imply this lemma.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Seconding Shaun, I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Appreciate it! Will do!